# MVC/JQuery Input set Value with .val()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, get

I have an input element that I am setting the value to be nothing initially:

```
<input id="fooValue" type="hidden" data-url="@Url.Action(MVC.fooController.fooValue())" value="" />
```

I then have an AJAX call where I retrieve a value and try to pass it into the input and set the previously blank value to this new value:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: $('#fooValue').data('url'),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#fooValue').val(data);
    }
});
```

When I perform this AJAX request in the Firebug console I get back the value of 4, however when I got to get the value from the input it isn't returning anything. Can anybody help me and tell me why it would appear that the value is not being set with the AJAX request? Thanks.

Comment: The following [post](http://www.codem0nk3y.com/2011/03/jquery-val-setter-not-working/) might be helpful.  Although his example involves a `HIDDEN` field I think you may be able to fix the problem by removing `value=""` from your HTML as described in the blog post.

Comment: That worked actually. Thank you. I now need to get the value into my value= correctly as right now I have value="[object Object] :) thanks.

Comment: What type of data are you returning? You might want to try `.val(data.d);`

Comment: I reposted my comment as an Answer.  I'd be grateful if you would mark it as Accepted.

Comment: If you always return a data.d, probably best to use a `converter` or `dataFilter:` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [post](http://www.codem0nk3y.com/2011/03/jquery-val-setter-not-working/) might be helpful. Although his example involves a HIDDEN field I think you may be able to fix your problem by removing `value=""` from your HTML as described in the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is an asynchronous request. may be you try with `async: false` in your ajax function?

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: $('#fooValue').data('url'),
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    $('#fooValue').val(data);
  }
});
```